# sql query to get records based on 2 ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 Tables IlRoutes and PlRoutes and they both have a common RouteID.

```
IlRoute:                          PlRoute:
RouteID   CID               RouteID  PlID Division
  1        3                   1      2     71
  2        3                   1      7     29
  3        3                   2      1     78
  4       37                   2      7     21
  5       37                   3      5     50
  6       37                   3      6     50
```

I want the records where plID = 7 and CID = 3 and also the records based on the RouteID's

Here is the sample output:

```
RouteID CID  RouteID  PlID Division 
  1      3     1       2     71
  1      3     1       7     29
  2      3     2       1     78
  2      3     2       7     21
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to return any record that matches with `cid = 3` in the `IlRoute` table, and at least one record in the PlRoute table `plId = 7`.

First `join` the tables together, and then use `exists` to see if there is at least one record with plid = 7:

```
select i.routeid, i.cid, p.plid, p.division
from ilroute i
  join plroute p on i.routeid = p.routeid 
where i.cid = 3 and 
  exists (select 1
                from PlRoute p2
                where p.routeid = p2.routeid 
                    and p2.plid = 7)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ab8c/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    IlRoute.*, PlRoute.* 
from 
    IlRoute 
join 
    PlRoute 
where 
    IlRoute.RouteID = PlRoute.RouteID
```

Comment: This is going to return all records that match on the `routeid`, regardless of `cid` and `plid`...

Answer (score 0):

```
 select IlRoute.RouteID, IlRoute.CID,  PlRoute.RouteID,  PlRoute.PlID, PlRoute.Division  
 from  IlRoute,PlRoute 
 where IlRoute.RouteID=PlRoute.RouteID 
 and   IlRoute.CID=3
```

Answer (score 0):

The following meets your criteria and should be the most efficient:

```
SELECT i.RouteID, i.CID, p.RouteID, p.PlID, pl.Division
FROM IlRoute i
INNER JOIN PlRoute p ON i.RouteID=p.RouteID
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM PlRoute WHERE RouteID=i.RouteID AND PlID=7) pCriteria
WHERE CID=3
```